Extending the Divergence Theorem to General Domains Using Partition of Unity
The Divergence Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is often first proved for simpler domains of the form
$
\Omega = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n > \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}) \},
$
where $\phi$ is a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. How can this result be extended to general domains with smooth boundaries (where a unit outward normal is well-defined) using a rigorous yet elementary approach, such as partition of unity?
I am specifically looking for a step-by-step proof that emphasizes:

Partitioning the domain into simpler pieces.

Using a partition of unity to manage overlaps and transitions.

Combining contributions to prove the theorem for the entire domain.


A clean proof or references (undergraduate level, without getting much into differential geometry) for this approach would be greatly appreciated!
